# Application is stopped with facebook login button

Tags: android, facebook-login

i want implement facebook login in my android app but when onCreate set the layout my app crash.

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LoginButton facebookLoginButton;
    private CallbackManager callbackManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    System.out.println("Prova 1");
    try {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }catch(Exception exc){
        System.out.println("Errore activity "+exc);
    }
    System.out.println("Prova 2");

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    System.out.println("Prova 3");  

    }

}
```

**Module:app   build.gradle**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:fb="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp" />
```

The system print only "Prova 1" and I don't know why!

This is the **manifest**:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <activity
                android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
                android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
```

with **meta-data**:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
```

My phone have api 19 but the application work with 15 to 23 api. I have copy this code also in other application find online [login-basic](https://github.com/andrebts/login-basics) where not crash.

What is my error ? It's some day that i test this but nothing, please help me!
Thank you!!

--------------------------------------------------Updating-----------------

Excuse me , I had already set the permissions for Internet. The problem is when the main build the `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` and i don't know why. In the activity_main there is only the facebook button. Also, i try this code in a new project and that's why I put everything in the main.

The catch error is: I/System.out: Errore android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #14: Error inflating class com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton

Comment: Please post your logcat output.

Comment: Please post your proper `MainActivity.java` code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been into same problem and the solution wan to initialize facebooksdk before calling setContentView function like this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

As you are using facebook LoginButton which is a view so the initialization has to be made before your UI content is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, i do believe you need an internet connection in order to access Facebook. However, in your manifest file you have not added the internet permission so please do as follows

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Secondly, it seems you are running the Facebook login process on the main thread of your app which is not a good idea. Use Async Tasks would be a better option.You can read more on them at http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
In addition to this, it is good practice to use "Try " and "Catch" to prevent your app from crashing completely. It usually has the following syntax

```
Try

//Block of Code Here

Catch Exception()
```

Comment: Excuse me , I had already set the permissions for Internet. The problem is when the main build the setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); and i don't know why. In the activity_main there is only the facebook button. Also, i try this code in a new project and that's why I put everything in the main